# Advice on web server performance troubleshooting is needed

Tags: centos, performance, troubleshooting, vmstat

I'm renting a virtual CentOS based server where I have about 5 active sites running. Several months ago I noticed a significant performance degradation in how my sites are running.

First symptom was too many (~300) apache processes running after that HTTP server stops responding. The problem disappeared after reboot but appeared again sporadically in a day or in a week and so on. I played with httpd.config options but couldn't get rid of that problem and the only solution I could found is to schedule server reboot every 1 hour. The reboot was quite fast so temporary it solved the problem.

However a couple months ago I started observing another problem with server performance - periodically sites just respond too slowly.

I need some advice or help to figure out the source of problem as I'm not sure I understand it for the moment:

It looks like it's enough memory, here is the output from top:
Mem:    524288k total,   299252k used,   225036k free,        0k buffers

It's enough disk space (from "vm -h"):

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
vzfs                   40G   28G   13G  70% /
none                  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
```

And here is runtime information about resource usage from "vmstat -S M 2 100":

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0    220      0      0    0    0     8   111    0    1  6  4 90  0  0
 0  0      0    220      0      0    0    0     0     0    0  272  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0    220      0      0    0    0     0     0    0  176  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0    220      0      0    0    0     0     0    0  132  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0    220      0      0    0    0     0  1950    0  330  0  0 100  0  0
 2  0      0    220      0      0    0    0     0     4    0 1854 21 19 60  0  0
 2  0      0    210      0      0    0    0     0     4    0 1958 73 23  4  0  0
 2  0      0    199      0      0    0    0     0     4    0  829 41 40 19  0  0
 1  0      0    207      0      0    0    0     0    26    0 1212 47 17 36  0  0
 1  0      0    206      0      0    0    0     0     4    0 1405 50  4 45  0  0
 0  0      0    209      0      0    0    0     4   140    0 1251 34  5 60  0  0
 0  0      0    208      0      0    0    0     0     0    0  213  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0    208      0      0    0    0     0     0    0  353  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0    208      0      0    0    0     0     6    0  317  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0    206      0      0    0    0     0     0    0  299  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0    214      0      0    0    0    12   114    0  336  0  1 99  0  0
```

By the way, the lines with high CS (context switching values) correspond to moments when I refreshed a couple site pages.

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: What is your database doing at that time? Is those statistics from a time when server gets slow?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I find that when apache is set so that it is allowed to spawn more children than you can handle, it freezes once it reaches your system limit. It's not very good at freeing up resources once it's clogged. So I suggest you tone down your max child (by a lot) for apache to begin with. See how much memory 1 child typically uses. Then divide your max avl ram with how much 1 child uses and you can use that result as your starting point of tweaking for what optimal child count may be.

My answer may be biased, but I do not find apache is very good at being a web server... It's far too resource consumptive than it needs to be and thus especially makes a poor choice for small environments like the VPS you're running. Try an alternative like nginx (with php-fpm if you're using php for example), or varnish, etc. These are not 1 to 1 replacement of apache, but they are web servers that I find to be lot more efficient and less prone to freezing up due to resource issues.

Also, when posting issues like this, I recommend you post stats from things like `top` as they provide a more complete picture, albeit general, during your peak/troublesome time.